# List Selected item is not deselected

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In a Spark based List I was trying to deselect an item in the List. I was doing this by setting the selectedIndex to -1 or List.NO_SELECTION. However, the previous item was constantly selected. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that in the previous code I had called myArrayCollection.refresh() and had not yet validated the list before setting the selectedIndex.

This list would call the mx_internal dataProviderRefreshed() method and put it into a invalidProperties state. This schedule the list to clear the selection index and caret index (and in my case reselect the previously selectedIndex).

```
/**
 *  @private
 *  Default response to dataProvider refresh events: clear the selection and caret.
 */
mx_internal function dataProviderRefreshed():void
{
    setSelectedIndex(NO_SELECTION, false);
    setCurrentCaretIndex(NO_CARET);
}
```

The solution was to call list.validateNow() after calling refresh() on the dataProvider's array collection and setting the selectedIndex after that.